# RDF Usage Rates for Syndication

Tags: rss, rdf, syndication

Is RDF still used widely for content syndication? Specifically, I know only of Slashdot as a large scale website syndicating content in that format (say versus RSS).

Understandably this might seem vague to answer so more specifically:

- Can anyone list any larger sites similar in scale to Amazon or CNN using it?
- Any web based publishing platforms (Wordpress, Joomla, etc...) that generate syndication feeds with this xml vocabulary.
- Any other more quantifiable evidence that it is used for syndication online.

I understand that RDF may be a parent specification but in this case I'm talking about sites that syndicate content using <rdf> as a root element and heavily leveraging elements from the RDF namespace: 
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial versions of RSS were RDF based, but newer ones are XML languages without RDF syntax elements.

Here is a link one the different RSS versions : http://diveintomark.org/archives/2004/02/04/incompatible-rss

I believe RSS 2.0 and Atom are currently more common for syndication than RDF based RSS formats.